# Extract nested microdata using xpath

Tags: xpath, schema

I am trying to extract the recipe name from schema.org microdata using xpath

This is the xpath I came up with:

```
//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"]//*[@itemprop="name" and not(ancestor::*[@itemtype!="http://schema.org/Recipe"])]
```

Select the node with `itemprop="name"` inside the node with `itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"`, but ignore nodes with a non-recipe itemtype parent (within the scope of the `itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"` node).

Test cases:

Fails:

```
<div itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing">
  <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
    <div>
      <div itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
          <div itemprop="name">test1</div>
          <div itemprop="name">test2</div>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="name">Recipe Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fails:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
  <div>
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
      <div>
        <div itemprop="name">test1</div>
        <div>
            <div itemprop="name">test2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div itemprop="name">Recipe Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Passes:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
  <div>
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
        <div itemprop="name">test1</div>
        <div itemprop="name">test2</div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="name">Recipe Name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Passes:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
  <div itemprop="name">Recipe Name</div>
</div>
```

It appears that `ancestor::*[@itemtype!="http://schema.org/Recipe"]` is searching all ancestors instead of just ancestors within the `Recipe` node.

How can I extract the recipe name from Recipe microdata https://schema.org/Recipe when there are potentially nested itemtypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to include all `Recipe Name` and exclude all `testx`, this expression

```
//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"]//*[@itemprop="name"][not(..[@itemtype!="http://schema.org/Recipe"])]
```

or, simpler version:

```
//*[contains(@itemtype,"Recipe")]//*[@itemprop="name"][not(../@itemtype[not(contains(.,"Recipe"))])]
```

should do it.

Edit:

Using the updated samples:

```
//*[contains(@itemtype,"Recipe")]//*[@itemprop="name"][not(ancestor::*[@itemtype][1]/@itemtype[not(contains(.,"Recipe"))])]
```

That's xpath double negation for you...

Comment: This assumes that the direct parent of the node will be the 'itemtype' node, but I don't think that is a requirement for using microdata https://schema.org/docs/gs.html I updated the question with another test case

Comment: @StackOverflower OK, I think I see it now; try with the edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be (since the `Recipe name` seems always in the last node) :

```
(//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"]//*[@itemprop="name"])[last()]
```

It passes the 4 sample tests.